Creating a std::array of templated functions results based on the types of a tuples elements
I want to create an array where each element is (at runtime) calculated based on the type of each element of a Tuple. In practice I want to assign a runtime id to each type that exists in a tuple by calling getId on them.
template <Typename TupleType>
auto getIds() {
...
}

//So when calling  
getIds<std::tuple<A, B, C>>()
    
//I want it to return a  
std::array{ getId<A>(), getId<B>(), getId<C>() }. 

And as mentioned above getId() is a runtime function, not constexpr.
I have tried many different solutions but I often end up with the problem of how to correctly unpack the tuple to parameter packs and then use index_sequence<> and make_index_sequence<>.

Why not use template parameter packs, and declare the function something like template<typename A, ...> auto getIds();? I don't know if it will help, but it's just an idea.

If you drop that you need a to pass in a tuple the code become very trivial: template<typename... Ts> auto getIds() { return std::array{getId<Ts>()...}; }

@NathanOliver, The Tuples comes upstream, from argument types of some lambdas. I need them as tuples in order to remove qualifiers, store them and later use them to invoke/apply the lambda. But yes, that is ultimately a solution, with some refactoring. I still find it surprisingly hard to deal with interop between tuples and parameter packs, especially when considering storage of them.

If you don't have to take a tuple the code can be simplified to
template<typename... Ts> 
auto getIds() 
{
    return std::array{getId<Ts>()...};
}

If you need to handle the tuple instead then it gets a little more complicated since we create an index_sequence to get each element type of the tuple.  To do that we can leverage an immediately invoked lambda expression that we pass the index_sequence to. That would give you
template <Typename TupleType>
auto getIds() 
{
                                // no parameter name to avoid unused warning
    return []<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
           {
                // make array like the first example geting the id for each element
                return std::array{getId<std::tuple_element_t<Is, TupleType>>()...};
            }(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<TupleType>>{});
            // create index_sequence based on the size of the tuple and call the lambda to return the array
}

